# Can Thresh's E cancel dashes?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was in a game the other day, playing bot lane with my friend.  We got ganked by a Jarvan, who proceeded to place a flag behind us and try to dash to it.  But, due to my epic skills and reaction time I landed an E and threw him off of us before his dash finished (totally a lucky shot).  I was wondering if Thresh's E can also cancel other dashes like that one.  To give a few examples, Vi's ultimate, Malphite's ultimate, and Maokai's Twisted Advance?

Comment: This has already been answered, but I wanted to supply a good source of answers for questions like these. The LoL wiki has articles for every champion and usually covers special interactions and specific details of every champion ability. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But, some dashes make the person dashing unstoppable or untargetable. All of the examples you listed make the dasher unstoppable or untargetable. Vi's ult and Malph's ult both make them unstoppable, and Maokai's W makes him untargetable. You just have to memorize whose dashes do what. Dashes like Vi's Q and Lucian's E can be interrupted by abilities like Thresh's flay.

Comment: Btw, nice timing with that flay XD

Comment: Thanks lol, so things like Sion's ult or Hecarim's wouldn't be able to be affected, but a dash or jump like Tristana's rocket jump or graves' dash can be?  Nice.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Knock-Backs like Vayne's E also

Comment: A rough rule of thumb is that most ultimates will not be stopped. Some "targetted on a person" dashes like Yi and Moakai will not be stopped but pretty much all non-ultimate non-targeted dashes like tristana jump, corki jump, etc will be stopped.